# Run a function after keypress in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want MATLAB to run a function after I press a specific key "s" from the keyboard while I am within the MATLAB application (focused in MATLAB window). Is there a way to do that without the use of any external packages or libraries?

Thank you.

Comment: You want it to run when you're in MS word? When you type it into the command window? When you are within a custom GUI? You need to be more specific here

Comment: @Wolfie Sorry you're are right, I forgot to mention that. I will edit the question.

Comment: That hasn't helped much. "within the matlab application" - if you are within the text editor or command window this will obviously just type an s?

Comment: @Wolfie as I said I am waiting for a key press to run a function. The function needs to run after I press the key so it doesn't matter if it types or not. It is just sort of a KeyPressFunction event to run a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom shortcuts in Matlab by selecting:

```
Home > Preferences > Shortcuts
```

The closest option to what you want is "evaluate entire file" which runs the current script / function file open in the editor. I don't know of any ability to run a specific function using this, but you can assign the shortcut "S" as shown below.

[image: preferences]